# TypeError : Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync is not a function

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I am trying out expo-notifications for the first time. I have run into an error that says  **TypeError : Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync is not a function**

Here is my code :

```
import * as Notifications from 'expo';

enableNotifications = () =>{
 Notifications.scheduleNotificationAsync({ 
      content : {
        title : 'Notification',
        body : 'This is a notification'
      }
    })
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more code snippet for same. Looks like you're not importing function correctly. The import statement must be like `import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';`

Comment: I had imported notifications from the expo, should I change it to expo-notifications?